# How do you generate positive definite matrix in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to define Multivariate Gaussian distribution with randomly generated covariance matrix:

```
psi = torch.zeros(512).normal_(0., 1.).requires_grad_(True)

# Generate random matrix
Sigma_k = torch.rand(512, 512)
# Make it symmetric positive
Sigma_k = Sigma_k * Sigma_k.t()
# Make it definite
Sigma_k.add_(0.001, torch.eye(512)).requires_grad_(True)

multivariate_normal.MultivariateNormal(psi, Sigma_k)
```

But I end up with getting an exception:

> RuntimeError: Lapack Error in potrf : the leading minor of order 2 is not positive definite at /Users/soumith/mc3build/conda-bld/pytorch_1549597882250/work/aten/src/TH/generic/THTensorLapack.cpp:658

What is the proper way to generate positive definite square matrix?

Comment: which PyTorch version are you using? Not sure if this helps: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/8196

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is one should make a dot product of matrix `A` and it's transpose matrix (`A.t()`) in order to obtain a positive semi-definite matrix. The last thing is to ensure that it is definite (strictly greater than zero).

With Pytorch:

```
Sigma_k = torch.rand(512, 512)
Sigma_k = torch.mm(Sigma_k, Sigma_k.t())
Sigma_k.add_(torch.eye(512))
```

Formal algorithm is described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357980/how-to-generate-random-symmetric-positive-definite-matrices-using-matlab).

Comment: Is there also a simple way to test if a matrix is indeed symmetric and positive-semidefinite?

Comment: I think if you follow the steps it basically describes the definition of positive-definite matrix.

Answer (score 5):

In "make it definite"

`tensor.add()` does not change `tensor`, but only returns a changed version.
You want to use `tensor.add_()`

Comment: Yes, it is a misprint. Though, it doesn't solve initial problem.